# link_to does not render dynamic data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My main page content is generated with this code:

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post" style="background:url(<%= post.postimg.url.to_s%>)center center">
    <div class="overlay">
    <p class="post_title"><%= post.titre %></p>
    <p class="post_pseudo"><%= link_to Utilisateur.find(post.utilisateur_id).pseudo ,Utilisateur.find(post.utilisateur_id).pseudo %></p>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This snippet is inn `_postgeneration.html.erb`. The main page (`index.html.erb` ) look like this :

```
<%= render "headerhome"%>
<%= render "postgeneration"%>
```

When the user is redirected from a controller with `redirect_to` , everything works as expected, my posts are displayed. But when my page is generated from a `link_to`, only my HTML is displayed correctly. Here's my syntax for `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "homepage", '/home'%>
```

It looks like `link_to` refuse to render html elements dynamically generated.

Comment: how do you redirect from the controller?

Comment: with the helper redirect_to , this way : redirect_to '/home'. Someone downvote my post, but i search the internet all afternoon yesterday to find the answer.

Comment: could you please show the code in home controller?

Comment: def index
    @pseudo = session[:utilisateur_pseudo]
    @post = Post.all
    
  end


`

Comment: What is in your routes.rb file?
Is /home set as a get request to serve the index action?

Comment: Yes, i think it is.                                                `resources :homes 
    match '/home'=>'homes#index', :via => [:get]
      resources :homes do 
        get 'index'
      end`

Comment: So it ignores anything in @post.each do ....?  I believe if it's empty then it no longer raises an error but doesn't do the block so for some reason it's not setting @post.  You should remove `resources :homes do get 'index' end` from routes, the index route is defined by resources anyway and you shouldn't have the same resource defined twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@post.each do` **wasn't ignored**. The post were generated, but without visual, because the visual was set in **inline css**. The solution was to delete the inline css and put a image_tag. Now everything is working as expected. I didn't know Rails could ignore inline css. Thanks everyone !